# Solve age-structured SIR model (i.e. a PDE) in Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to solve an age-structured model of disease transmission, where people fall into four compartments: susceptible to both strains, $x(a,t)$; those who have been exposed to strain 1, $z_1(a,t)$; those who have been exposed to strain 2, $z_2(a,t)$; and those who have been exposed to both strains, $z_{12}(a,t)$.

Suppose that the compartments represent proportions, so that:

$x+z_1+z_2+z_{12}=1$.

We suppose that there are age and strain-dependent forces of infection ($\lambda_1(a,t)$ and $\lambda_2(a,t)$ for strains 1 and 2), that can vary over time. As such, the model governing disease dynamics can be written as a system of PDEs:

$\frac{\partial x}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = -x (\lambda_1 + \lambda_2),$
$\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial z_1}{\partial t} = x \lambda_1 - z_1 \lambda_2,$
$\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial a} + \frac{\partial z_2}{\partial t} = x \lambda_2 - z_2 \lambda_1.$

I am trying to solve these in MMA, and have tried the following:

```
DSolve[
{D[x[a, t], a] + D[x[a, t], t] == -x[a, t] (\[Lambda]1 [a, t] + \[Lambda]2 [a, t]),
 D[z1[a, t], t] + D[z1[a, t], a] == x[a, t] \[Lambda]1 [a, t] - z1[a, t] \[Lambda]2[a, t], 
 D[z2[a, t], t] + D[z2[a, t], a] == x[a, t] \[Lambda]2 [a, t] - z2[a, t] \[Lambda]1[a, t]},
{x[a, t], z1[a, t], z2[a, t]}, {a, t}]
```

which returns unevaluated.

Any idea how to solve this in MMA/otherwise?

Note: I can solve similar, but simpler, systems in MMA. For example, for a single strain case, the following:

```
DSolve[{
  D[z[a, t], t] + D[z[a, t], a] == (1 - z[a, t]) \[Lambda][a, t]}, z[a, t], {a, t}]
```

returns a solution (that I am struggling to paste here for some formatting reasons).

Comment: I'm not an expert in this area, but are the $\lambda$'s constants or functions of the infected, $z$'s?  Also, do you need a boundary condition to replenish the susceptibles, $x$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The $\lambda$s are functions of age and time (not of the proportion infected here). I am assuming that the population size is fixed over the period of the epidemic (which is very short compared to lifespan of people), so, in this case, there is no need for a replenishment of susceptibles.

Comment: This might b helpful: [Modeling a Pandemic like Ebola with the Wolfram Language](https://blog.wolfram.com/2014/11/04/modeling-a-pandemic-like-ebola-with-the-wolfram-language)

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov -- thanks. Not sure they are the same though: the link (as far as I am aware) is a standard SIR model. Here, I am trying to solve an age-structured one.

Comment: @ben18785 I see.  Could you give the values of the $\lambda$'s?

Comment: @ChrisK, they are any non-negative functions that can be integrated (I am trying to solve the problem in its generality).

Comment: @ben18785: Have you developed the solution to your age-dependent SIR model? I have a similar problem as yours. I have an economic model with 2 sectors in which employers of each sector face a different infection rate depending on the proximity of working distance. Another addition, or complication, in my model is that the model should be run capturing all the sectors (simultaneous system of equations) because non-working people have relations with the working people represented as a different equation. Let me know what you think? Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Since the infection rates $\lambda$ don't depend on the number of infecteds, this isn't the usual nonlinear SIR model that would require numerical solution with `NDSolve`.  Because your model is thankfully linear, it should be analytically solvable.

Rather than solving the full PDE model, it seems easier to follow the dynamics of a cohort with initial age $a=a_0$.  Different cohorts don't interact, so you can treat them separately with their own ODEs.  Age simply increases linearly with time, $a(t)=a_0+t$ (*sigh*).  Inject that into your equations and `DSolve` gives a solution:

```
DSolve[{
  x'[t] == -x[t] (λ1[t, a0 + t] + λ2[t, a0 + t]), 
  z1'[t] == x[t] λ1[t, a0 + t] - z1[t] λ2[t, a0 + t], 
  z2'[t] == x[t] λ2[t, a0 + t] - z2[t] λ1[t, a0 + t], 
  x[0] == x0, z1[0] == z10, z2[0] == z20}, {x, z1, z2}, t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is even uglier than it should be, since Mathematica seems fixated with including time $t=1$ in the integrals, but you can fix that by hand.

Comment: Thanks! I'm leaving open for now am still surprised that MMA couldn't solve the system of PDEs itself (as it does for the lower dimension setting).

Comment: @ben18785 I imagine different kinds of systems need to be coded separately within `DSolve` and these age-structured PDEs might not have made the cut.  Anyhow, I'd also be happy if they could be solved directly and also if someone could say how to get rid of the `t=1` in the integrals in my answer.

Comment: Yes, true. Just found it weird that, in my question, I show how a low dim PDE system can be solved but that MMA just falls over immediately for a slightly higher dim system.